# PHP or Python for creating webcharts after calculations?

Tags: php, python, charts

Is it a good idea to code such a script in Python and in which language is handy for fast performance and useful libraries/frameworks for charts?(charts would be created after calculating an expression which is input from the user)

EDIT:It's a web server-side script

Comment: What is the server-side script that "calculates the expression" already coded in?  PHP or Python, they are both very capable of charting/plotting.  They both have multiple charting libraries.  They both perform well.

Comment: Python.I have heard that php is faster than python for some things and I was asking for idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "charts", but if you mean plotting/creating graphs, perhaps you should look at [R](http://www.r-project.org/), a free software environment for statistical computing and graphics.  It has good graphics capabilities, and can connect to many environments, including Python.

Comment: i guess i forgot to specify...it's a web application.So I have to convert the charts to images and I wonder if there isn't native php or python technic

Answer (score 1):

For Python - check [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) - it should do everything you need to do, including outputting to PNG, JPEG, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's reasonably straightforward to generate graphics on the fly in python using the reportlab library http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/. It includes functionality to create bar, line, pie, etc. charts from lists of data. Don't be misled by the emphasis on generating PDFs, the library also can create just PNG or GIF images. Also, the official documentation is very verbose and intimidating, but it's quite accessible once you actually start coding.

The following page explains the whole process for Django, but the same approach would be applicable to any framework: http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Charts.

In particular, note that you can build a graphic in-memory and return it as an HttpResponse. It's quite fast. I use something like the following in one of my apps:

```
def my_chart(request):
    response = HttpResponse(
        my_function_to_make_a_chart().asString('png'),
        'image/png',
    )
    return response
```

That django view would be associated with a URL that you would embed directly into your HTML document as an  tag:

```
<img src="/my_site/my_chart/" alt="A cool chart" />
```

Comment: that's interesting,the HttpResponse idea is cool!Just curious is it necessary to use a framework or it is not a lot of code in pure Python

Comment: Generating the chart is just python (using the reportlab library). What are you using now to run your server-side script? Just CGI? It's possible to do so, but a framework handles a lot of the boilerplate for you. You could use Flask if you want something minimal: <http://flask.pocoo.org/>.